# Calling Script from Command line not working

Tags: python, cygwin, ctypes, command-prompt

We created a DLL using cygwin and have written a class based python module for the same. We have created a sample script for the class based python module, that creates an object of the class and calls various methods in the class. This Test script works fine while I run it from IDLE. However when I run it from command prompt it either hangs or just returns without executing the functions. When it returns I do not get a error trace.

When I tried to findout where exactly the issue is happening. the issue occurs when I try to call the cygwin_dll_init method of the cygwin1.dll . This cygwin1.dll is actualy a dependency to the DLL we have built. So we have to load this DLL and call this cygwin_dll_init method before loading my DLL.

```
cyg = cdll.LoadLibrary("cygwin1.dll")

cyg.cygwin_dll_init() #hangs or returns here

mydll=cdll.LoadLibrary("my.dll")
mydll.func1()
```

I'm trying to understand what exactly is the difference, when we call it IDLE and when we call it from command prompt using the python command. I will have to get the script working from command prompt as well.

Thanks,
Sathish

Comment: hey, Thanks for replying. my.dll works without any issues with the Cygwin Python. Cygwin currently does not support the -mno -cygwin option. So I'm trying to compile the code using MinGW. But I'm stuck because one of the libraries that I'm using has a call to the fmemopen function which is not supported in MinGW. So I'm trying to figure out a how to replace it.

Comment: Can you run it through strace?

Comment: cygwin and native dll cannot be mixed, so if your code is not portable on native win32 (e.g. mingw) you should use cygwin python, for cygwin python there is no need to load cygwin dll, since it is already loaded with python interpreter

Comment: there are no fmemopen equivalents on win32 because of missing functionality in the kernel, I think cygwin implements it using a temp file like this one: https://redmine.openinfosecfoundation.org/embedded/suricata/util-fmemopen_8c-source.html